# Replace same variables in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a main `DF` (`DF_1`) that I frequently add new rows. However, before adding, I need to verify that the information that is in `DF_1` (`ID`) is also in this new file (`DF_2`). My key is the ID.
`DF_1`:

```
ID <- c(111,222,333,444,555,666)
CAR <- c('BMW','BMW','BMW','FERRARI','FERRARI','VW')
DATE <- c('OCT','NOV','DEC','OCT','DEC','DEC')
TIME <- c(10,12,15,7,11,14)
QUANTITY <- c(115,101,95,88,130,101)
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID,CAR,DATE,TIME,QUANTITY)
```

Below, DF_2 shows that IDs 222 and 444 are already in DF_1. For some reason, these IDs have changed.
`DF_2`:

```
ID <- c(222,444,777,888)
CAR <- c('FORD','TOYOTA','SUBARU','NISSAN')
DATE <- c('JAN','FEB','APR','MAY')
TIME <- c(20,33,45,79)
QUANTITY <- c(12,66,31,15)
DF_2 <- data.frame(ID,CAR,DATE,TIME,QUANTITY)
```

Thus, I need the same IDs (in this example 222 and 444) to be replaced and the new IDs to be included, as the result I expect in `DF_FINAL`.

```
DF_FINAL

ID <- c(111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888)
CAR <- c('BMW','FORD','BMW','TOYOTA','FERRARI','VW','SUBARU','NISSAN')
DATE <- c('OCT','JAN','DEC','FEB','DEC','DEC','APR','MAY')
TIME <- c(10,20,15,33,11,14,45,79)
QUANTITY <- c(115,12,95,66,130,101,45,79)
DF_FINAL <- data.frame(ID,CAR,DATE,TIME,QUANTITY)
```

How do I replace all rows of the same IDs and add the different IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rows_upsert` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_upsert(DF_1, DF_2)
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know this code, very simple. Thanks!